# How to set NodeOptions for a ComposableNode in a .launch.py file?

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm modifying a ROS2 node to be a component, and I'm trying to set additional node options when launching this node. Here is a snippet from a genericized but representative launch file:

```
def generate_launch_description():
        container = ComposableNodeContainer(
            name='test_container',
            namespace='/',
            package='rclcpp_components',
            executable='component_container',
            composable_node_descriptions=[
                ComposableNode(
                    package='my_package',
                    plugin='my_package::MyComponentNode',
                    name='test_node',
                    extra_arguments=[{'use_intra_process_comms' : True, 'automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides': True, 'allow_undeclared_parameters': True}]),
            ],
    )
    return LaunchDescription([container] )
```

In my node's constructor I'm querying the options that were passed in:

```
class MyComponentNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  MyComponentNode(const rclcpp::NodeOptions& options) : rclcpp::Node("test_node", options)
  {      
    RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(LOGGER, "use_intraprocess_comms: " << get_node_options().use_intra_process_comms() << " allow undeclared params: " << get_node_options().allow_undeclared_parameters() << " auto declare params: " << get_node_options().automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides());
  }
}
```

I can see that `use_intra_process_comms` is being set correctly (and I can toggle it between True and False by changing my launch file), but `automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides` and `allow_undeclared_parameters` are not set to True like I would expect:

```
[component_container-4] [INFO] [1616010417.606922763] [test_node]: use_intraprocess_comms: 1 allow undeclared params: 0 auto declare params: 0
```

What is the correct way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374209/how-to-set-nodeoptions-for-a-composablenode-in-a-.launch.py-file?/) by [jschornak](https://answers.ros.org/users/37574/jschornak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2021-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the source code of the [component_manager](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/master/rclcpp_components/src/component_manager.cpp#L173), it looks like only `use_intra_process_comms` can be set from `extra_arguments` the other arguments will be ignored

---

Originally posted by [jafar_abdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25259/jafar_abdi/) with karma: 221 on 2021-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1